# Разбить один div на 2 колонки. не получается выполнить разметку

Tags: разметка, css

У меня на странице есть div.

Этот div надо разбить на две колонки:
колонка1 с шириной 70%
колонка2 с шириной 30%

Мои проблемы с высотой. Высота колонок может быть любой. Также, ширина колонок можно задаваться только в процентах.

Раньше у меня было это сделано на основе таблиц, то сейчас вроде используют css: position, float. Реализовать такое решение у меня не получается :(

Вот изображение: http://s020.radikal.ru/i709/1406/c3/2f9021202ede.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="div1">div1</div>
<div class="div2">div2</div>
<div class="footer"></div>
```

CSS

```
.div1{    
    width: 70%;
    min-height: 150px;
    background: #ccc;
    float: left;
}
.div2{    
    width: 30%;
    min-height: 150px;
    background: #c00;   
    margin-left: 70%;
}
.footer{
    clear: left;
    background: #000;
    min-height: 50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dn5r3/

Comment: А почему footer получается немножко шире ?

Answer (score 2):

Если браузеры современные используйте `flexbox`

```css
.flex-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.first {
  background: red;
  height: 300px;
  flex-grow: 3;
}

.second {
  background: green;
  height: 300px;
  flex-grow: 7;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

`

Answer (score 1):

```css
#left_container {
  width: 70%;
  min-height: 150px;
  background: #ccc;
  float: left;
}

#right_container {
  width: 30%;
  min-height: 150px;
  background: #c00;
  float: right;
}
```